# vertical space after (not between) items

Tags: spacing, lists

I just want to add some vertical space *after* each item in a list. However, the usual options provided by list customization packages only modify the space *between* items.

In other words, I want to insert N vertical spaces after N items, not like `itemize` does, which inserts N-1 vertical spaces between N elements (by increasing the `itemsep` dimension provided by the `enumitem` package)

*Note.* I would like to insert space in a systematic way (see the MWE), since my final goal is to define a new environment that does it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First question
\begin{itemize}
\item Solve: $x^2+1=0$
\vspace{2em}
\item Solve: $x^3+1=0$
\vspace{2em}
\item Solve: $x^4+1=0$
\vspace{2em}
\end{itemize}
\item Second question
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between the vertical space after an item and the vertical space between this item and the following item?

Comment: Space "after" an item takes effect over the N items (including the last one). whereas space "between" items is reffered to the N-1 locations between the N items. I hope to be clear now.

Comment: Not really – what's the difference  to the eye, as a final result? One can neutralise the space after the last item, or add space anyway

Comment: Okay, I try again. If, for example, you use \begin{itemize}[itemsep=3em] (a key-argument provided by the enumitem package), you won't obtain the vertical space that you can see in the MWE after the third item in the itemize list. However, I want that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I well understood what you want, here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First question
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=3em, after=\vspace*{\dimexpr 3em-\topsep-\partopsep}]
\item Solve: $x^2+1=0$
\item Solve: $x^3+1=0$
\item Solve: $x^4+1=0$
\end{itemize}
\item Second question
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! This was all

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation!